# Elementary derivation of entanglement entropy of an interval in a CFT?

Tags: entropy, conformal-field-theory

In CFT entanglement entropy of an interval of length $l$ scales as $S(l)=\frac{c}3\log l$. I am familiar with the derivation of this result from correlators of twist fields, a technique due to Calebrese and Cardy. I am looking for a more direct derivation via partial tracing the vacuum state and evaluation of resulting von Neumann/Renyi entropies. Can it be found somewhere? Computations for free boson/fermion systems would be good enough.

Comment: You might find something close to what you're looking for in [Aspects of Entanglement Entropy in Algebraic Quantum Field Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.13975) and the references it cites. It's relatively thorough ($>300$ pages). It's not specific to CFT, but it does include sections about free bosons and free fermions.